# How to differentiate between these two matcher regex patterns

Tags: regex

I have a dev server and a production server.
Upon scanning a qr code, I use a matcher to check which server should be in use

dev server is:

```
dev.example.com/product
```

production server is:

```
example.com/product
```

Here are the matcher patterns:

```
private static String PRODUCT_CODE_PATTERN_DEV = "^https?://.*\\.example\\.com/product/(?:[A-Z]{2})?01([A-Za-z0-9]{6})([0-9-][0-9]{2})$";
private static String PRODUCT_CODE_PATTERN_PRODUCTION = "^https?://.*\\.example\\.com/product/(?:[A-Z]{2})?01([A-Za-z0-9]{6})([0-9-][0-9]{2})$";
```

As you can see at the moment they are equal, because I dont know what this part: `//.*\\.` stands for before `example\\.com/product/`so I dont know how to place "dev" there.

A developer before has came up with these patterns, so that explains how I have them, not knowing how are they generated.

Here is some example usage of the patterns:

```
private void getProductIdAndPrice(String url) {

    String id = "";
    int price = 0;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Constant.getProductCodePattern());
    for (MatchResult match : allMatches(pattern, url)) {
        String mydata = match.group();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            id = matcher.group(1);
            price = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
            ..
        }
    }
}

public static String getProductCodePattern() {
    if (MyApplication.useProductionEndpoint) {
        return PRODUCT_CODE_PATTERN_PRODUCTION;
    } else {
        return PRODUCT_CODE_PATTERN_DEV;
    }
}
```

Comment: Java?  Best to include the host language tag.

Comment: If you want to match dev URLs, you might want to add `dev` to the regex: `PRODUCT_CODE_PATTERN_DEV = "^https?://dev\\.example\\.com/product/(?:[A-Z]{2})?01([A-Za-z0-9]{6})([0-9-][0-9]{2})$";`

Comment: take a look at `//.*\\.`, be carefull `.*` is greedy and matching everything except newline. So remaining parts are doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//.*\\.`

- `//` just double slash
- `.*` greedy consumption of any character
- `\\.` is an escaped backslash followed by a dot so it becomes a literal dot.

From how the patterns are used (to extract the product ID from the url), I guess the reason there to be two of them is in case the dev server introduces a new product id system. For distinction between dev and production you seem to already have an own variable.
What prevents your strings from matching the production domain is the first `\\.` because it enforces a `.` before `example.com`. Remove it and the dot will be matched by `.*` if necessary.
It would actually make sense to use `.*?` instead of `.*` this will save the regex engine some steps. If a sub-pattern will potentially only match a few characters, like in this case, it is always better to use the non-greedy quantifier.

So in the end, what you likely need is:

```
private static String PRODUCT_CODE_PATTERN_DEV = "^https?://.*?example\\.com/product/(?:[A-Z]{2})?01([A-Za-z0-9]{6})([0-9-][0-9]{2})$";
private static String PRODUCT_CODE_PATTERN_PRODUCTION = "^https?://.*?example\\.com/product/(?:[A-Z]{2})?01([A-Za-z0-9]{6})([0-9-][0-9]{2})$";
```

If you really want to only match dev and production respectively you could use:

```
private static String PRODUCT_CODE_PATTERN_DEV = "^https?://dev\\.example\\.com/product/(?:[A-Z]{2})?01([A-Za-z0-9]{6})([0-9-][0-9]{2})$";
private static String PRODUCT_CODE_PATTERN_PRODUCTION = "^https?://(?:www\\.)?example\\.com/product/(?:[A-Z]{2})?01([A-Za-z0-9]{6})([0-9-][0-9]{2})$";
```

Note that I introduced `(?:www\\.)?` so that the production domain can still be prefixed by `www.` if necessary. You can remove that if you don't need it.

I would like to recommend [regex101](http://regex101.com). It explains all parts of a given regex and also lets you play around.

Answer (score 1):

`//.*\\.` stands for:

- `//` literal "//" as in the end of "http://"
- `.*` any text
- `\\.` a dot (the `\\` is because a dot needs to be escaped)

You can include the letters in the server address as literal, only dots need to be escaped:

Code:

```java
private static String PRODUCT_CODE_PATTERN_DEV = "^https?://dev\\.example\\.com/product/(?:[A-Z]{2})?01([A-Za-z0-9]{6})([0-9-][0-9]{2})$";
private static String PRODUCT_CODE_PATTERN_PRODUCTION = "^https?://example\\.com/product/(?:[A-Z]{2})?01([A-Za-z0-9]{6})([0-9-][0-9]{2})$";
```